# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/LineInputStream for send mail through Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Here my Exception `LineInputStream`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/LineInputStream
        at javax.mail.Session.loadProvidersFromStream(Session.java:928)
        at javax.mail.Session.access$000(Session.java:174)
        at javax.mail.Session$1.load(Session.java:870)
        at javax.mail.Session.loadAllResources(Session.java:1130)
        at javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:886)
        at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
        at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:299)
        at com.pack.utils.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:67)
        at com.pack.utils.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:34
)
    at com.pack.utils.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:133)
```

my dependency jars are **java 1.6** , **mailapi-1.4.4**

i'm getting error this line

```
sessions[0] = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solution helps me

I added File permission in **java.policy** file and I changed Java6 to Java7

```
permission java.io.FilePermission  "<<ALL FILES>>", "read"; };
```

java.policy file available in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0\lib\security` this path

Answer (score 4):

Add this to you pom, or the JAR to your classpath,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note that the latest version is 1.6.1.